# Using Query in Pandas to remove a vector of values

Tags: python, pandas

I work in R and this operation would be easy in tidyverse; However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do it in Python and Pandas.

Let's say we're using the gapminder dataset

```
data_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/resbaz/r-novice-gapminder-files/master/data/gapminder-FiveYearData.csv'
gapminder = pd.read_csv(data_url)
```

and let's say that I want to filter out from the dataset all year values that are equal to 1952 and 1957. I would think that something like this would work, but it doesn't:

```
vector = [1952, 1957]
gapminder.query("year isin(vector)")
```

I realize here that I've made a vector in what is really a list. When I try to pass those two year values into an array as `vector = pd.array(1952, 1957)` That doesn't work either.

In R, for instance, you would have to do something simple like

```
vector = c(1952, 1957)
gapminder %>% filter(year %in% vector)
#or
gapminder %>% filter(year %in% c(1952, 1957))
```

So really this is a two part question: first, how can I create a vector of many values (if I were pulling these values from another dataset, I believe that I could just use pd.to_numpy) and then how do I then remove all rows based on that vector of observations from a dataframe?

I've looked at a lot of different variations for using query like here, for instance, https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-filtering-data-with-pandas-query-method/, but this has been surprisingly hard to find.

*Here I am updating my question: I found that this isn't working if I pull a vector from another dataset (or even from the same dataset); for instance:

```
vector = (1952, 1957)

#how to take a dataframe and make a vector
#how to make a vector

gapminder.vec = gapminder\
.query('year == [1952, 1958]')\
[['country']]\
.to_numpy()

gap_sum = gapminder.query("year != @gapminder.vec")
gap_sum
```

I receive the following error:
[image]

Thanks much!

James

Comment: Is there any reason you have to use the query method? I think the most straightforward way would be something like `gapminder[~gapminder['year'].isin([1952,1957])]`

Comment: Thanks Derek...yes, I found that solution. I've always liked piping in R (chaining in Python). I just find that I make less errors/have fewer things to code. So query is, from my understanding, the best way of doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `in` or even `==` inside the query string like so:

```
# gapminder.query("year == @vector") returns the same result
print(gapminder.query("year in @vector"))

          country  year        pop continent  lifeExp    gdpPercap
0     Afghanistan  1952  8425333.0      Asia   28.801   779.445314
1     Afghanistan  1957  9240934.0      Asia   30.332   820.853030
12        Albania  1952  1282697.0    Europe   55.230  1601.056136
13        Albania  1957  1476505.0    Europe   59.280  1942.284244
24        Algeria  1952  9279525.0    Africa   43.077  2449.008185
...           ...   ...        ...       ...      ...          ...
1669   Yemen Rep.  1957  5498090.0      Asia   33.970   804.830455
1680       Zambia  1952  2672000.0    Africa   42.038  1147.388831
1681       Zambia  1957  3016000.0    Africa   44.077  1311.956766
1692     Zimbabwe  1952  3080907.0    Africa   48.451   406.884115
1693     Zimbabwe  1957  3646340.0    Africa   50.469   518.764268
```

The `@` symbol tells the query string to look for a variable named `vector` outside of the context of the dataframe.

---

There are a couple of issues with the updated component of your question that I'll address:

1. The direct issue you're receiving is because you're using double square brackets to select a column. By using a double square bracket, you're forcing the selected column to be returned as a 2d table (e.g. a dataframe that contains a single column), instead of just the column itself. To resolve this issue, simply get rid of the double brackets. The `to_numpy` is also not necessary.
2. in your `gap_sum` variable, you're checking where the values in `"year"` are not in your `gapminder.vec` - which is a `pd.Series` (array for more generic term) of country names. So these don't really make sense to compare.
3. Don't use `.` notation to create variables in python. You're not making a new variable, but are attaching a new attribute to an existing object. Instead use underscores as is common practice in python (e.g. use `gapminder_vec` instead of `gapminder.vec`)

```
# countries that have years that are either 1952 or 1958
#   will contain duplicate country names
gapminder_vec = gapminder.query('year == [1952, 1958]')['country']

# This won't actually filter anything- because `gapminder_vec` is 
#  a bunch of country names. Not years. 
gapminder.query("year not in @gapminder_vec")
```

Also to perform a filter rather than a subset:

```
vec = (1952, 1958)

# returns a subset containing the rows who have a year in `vec`
subset_with_years_in_vec = gapminder.query('year in @vec')

# return subset containing rows who DO NOT have a year in `vec`
subset_without_years_in_vec = gapminder.query('year not in @vec')
```

Comment: Beautiful...this is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks much! It works if I just use vector = (1952, 1957), so is this a vector in Python as well? I thought it would be specifically a tuple (which is what I get when I do ```type(vector)```?

Comment: Yeah- this should work for any  object of abstract type `Sequence`. Which is a fancy way of saying that this should work for objects of the type: `list` (square brackets), `tuple` (parentheses), `numpy.ndarray` (more akin to R's vectors), `pandas.Series` and anything similar.

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Cameron, I realized today that this isn't working if I pull the vector from a dataset. I've updated my question to be clearer on that point. Would love if you could help me out. Have tried putting it into a vector as to_numpy() and values()

Comment: Just edited my answer. If you have further specific questions, it would probably be best to open a new question since we're straying from the original topic a little bit :)

Comment: Awesome--so the real thing I was looking for there was the "not in"...I assumed that != and "not in" were equal here. Thanks for pointing out everything else as well: Pandas makes it much easier to crossover from R, but still making making Python learning mistakes. Correction: I see what you're saying with country vs year...that was a nonsensical mistake I made trying out different things.

Comment: Not to worry, it's all part of the learning process. Within a query string, `==` and `in` are exchangeable in a few cases. So I find it's a little better to be explicit and use `in` and `not in` when I know I want to a dataframe against a list of values, and not a singular value.

Answer (score 1):

To filter out years 1952 and 1957 you can use:

```
print(gapminder.loc[~(gapminder.year.isin([1952, 1957]))])
```

Prints:

```
                       country  year           pop continent   lifeExp      gdpPercap
2                  Afghanistan  1962  1.026708e+07      Asia  31.99700     853.100710
3                  Afghanistan  1967  1.153797e+07      Asia  34.02000     836.197138
4                  Afghanistan  1972  1.307946e+07      Asia  36.08800     739.981106
5                  Afghanistan  1977  1.488037e+07      Asia  38.43800     786.113360
6                  Afghanistan  1982  1.288182e+07      Asia  39.85400     978.011439
7                  Afghanistan  1987  1.386796e+07      Asia  40.82200     852.395945
8                  Afghanistan  1992  1.631792e+07      Asia  41.67400     649.341395
9                  Afghanistan  1997  2.222742e+07      Asia  41.76300     635.341351
10                 Afghanistan  2002  2.526840e+07      Asia  42.12900     726.734055
11                 Afghanistan  2007  3.188992e+07      Asia  43.82800     974.580338
14                     Albania  1962  1.728137e+06    Europe  64.82000    2312.888958
15                     Albania  1967  1.984060e+06    Europe  66.22000    2760.196931
16                     Albania  1972  2.263554e+06    Europe  67.69000    3313.422188
17                     Albania  1977  2.509048e+06    Europe  68.93000    3533.003910

...
```